# Multiple rows in one row SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to learning SQL. This is my table data:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id     Code Type    Mon     Tue     Wed     Thur    Friday  Sat    Sunday
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
332674  97  1       p       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
332674  97  NULL    NULL    p       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
332674  97  NULL    NULL    NULL    p       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
332674  97  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    P       NULL    NULL    NULL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can U show this data in one row, something like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id      Code  Type     Mon     Tue     Wed     Thur    Friday  Sat    Sunday
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
332674  97    1        p       P       P       P        NULL    NULL    NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to change the way you are inserting the data into the table. Most of your data is redundant and can be represented in a better way.

Comment: Your table data should look like the one row on it's own. What is the reason for having multiple rows, each representing "P" in a different place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use aggregate function

```
 select id,code,max(type),max(mon),max(tue),max(wed),max(thur),max(sat),max(sunday)
    from t group by id,code
```